# if and else condition problem running simulteneously

Tags: flutter

#I am trying to filter the database data according to selected date and show it in list and if the if condition doesnt matches i wanna show that last icon with text saying looks like there are no homework but the problem is when i add two data of different date then both the list and no data presented icon are showing at the same.[image]

```
   child: FutureBuilder<List<SavedHomeworkModel>>(
                                      future: DatabaseHelper.instance.getSavedHomework(),
                                      builder: (BuildContext context,AsyncSnapshot<List<SavedHomeworkModel>>homeworkSnapshot){
                                        if (!homeworkSnapshot.hasData){
                                          return Card(
                                              child: Center(
                                                  child: Row(
                                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                                    children: const [
                                                      Padding(
                                                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0,top: 20.0,bottom: 20.0),
                                                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                                      ),
                                                      Padding(
                                                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                                                        child: Text("Loading homework List"),
                                                      )
                                                    ],
                                                  )
                                              )
                                          );
                                        }
                                        return homeworkSnapshot.data.isEmpty?const Padding(
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
                                          child: Center(child: Text('No homework list to show')),
                                        ): SingleChildScrollView(
                                          child: Column(
                                            children: homeworkSnapshot.data.map((homework){
                                              if(dateController.text == homework.savedHomeworkSubmissionDate){
                                                return Padding(
                                                  padding: const EdgeInsets
                                                      .symmetric(vertical: 3),
                                                  child: SizedBox(
                                                    width: double.infinity,
                                                    // height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.105,
                                                    child: GestureDetector(
                                                      onTap: () {
                                                        Navigator.of(context)
                                                            .pushReplacement(
                                                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                                                builder: (ctx)=>HomeworkPostScreen(
                                                                  savedHomeworkId: homework
                                                                      .savedHomeworkId,
                                                                  savedHomeworkCName: homework
                                                                      .savedHomeworkClassName,
                                                                  savedHomeworkSName: homework
                                                                      .savedHomeworkSectionName,
                                                                  savedHomeworkSubName: homework
                                                                      .savedHomeworkSubjectName,
                                                                  savedHomeworkT: homework
                                                                      .savedHomeworkTitle,
                                                                  savedHomeworkL: homework
                                                                      .link,
                                                                  savedHomeworkD: homework
                                                                      .savedHomeworkDetail,
                                                                  savedHomeworkImgs: homework
                                                                      .savedHomeworkImage,
                                                                  savedHomeworkSD: homework
                                                                      .savedHomeworkSubmissionDate,
                                                                )));
                                                      },
                                                      child: Card(
                                                        elevation: 0.0,
                                                        child: Padding(
                                                          padding: const EdgeInsets
                                                              .symmetric(
                                                              horizontal: 10,
                                                              vertical: 5),
                                                          child: Row(
                                                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment
                                                                .start,
                                                            children: [
                                                              Padding(
                                                                padding: const EdgeInsets
                                                                    .symmetric(
                                                                    horizontal: 10),
                                                                child: Column(
                                                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment
                                                                      .start,
                                                                  children: [
                                                                    const SizedBox(
                                                                        height: 5),
                                                                    Text(homework
                                                                        .savedHomeworkTitle),
                                                                    const SizedBox(
                                                                        height: 50),
                                                                    Row(
                                                                      children: [
                                                                        const Text(
                                                                          "Deadline :",
                                                                          style: TextStyle(
                                                                              color: Colors
                                                                                  .black38),),
                                                                        Text(
                                                                          homework
                                                                              .savedHomeworkSubmissionDate,
                                                                          style: const TextStyle(
                                                                              color: Colors
                                                                                  .black38),)
                                                                      ],
                                                                    )
                                                                  ],
                                                                ),
                                                              ),

                                                              const SizedBox(
                                                                  width: 70),
                                                              Container(
                                                                height: 100,
                                                                width: 1,
                                                                color: Colors.blue,
                                                              ),

                                                              Expanded(
                                                                child: Padding(
                                                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                                      horizontal: 10),
                                                                  child: Column(
                                                                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                                                    children: [
                                                                      Text(homework.savedHomeworkSubjectName ??" ",
                                                                        style: const TextStyle(
                                                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                                            fontSize: 14),
                                                                        overflow: TextOverflow.clip,),
                                                                      const SizedBox(
                                                                          height: 20),
                                                                      Text(
                                                                        "Class: ",
                                                                        style: TextStyle(
                                                                            color: ColorCombination(0).appBarColor),),
                                                                      Text(
                                                                        "${homework.savedHomeworkClassName ??" "}(${homework.savedHomeworkSectionName ??" "})",
                                                                        style: TextStyle(
                                                                            color: ColorCombination(0).appBarColor),),
                                                                    ],
                                                                  ),
                                                                ),
                                                              )
                                                            ],
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                );
                                              }else if(dateController.text != homework.savedHomeworkSubmissionDate){
                                                return  Padding(
                                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 200),
                                                  child: Center(
                                                    child: Container(
                                                      height: 250,
                                                      width: double.infinity,
                                                      child: Column(
                                                        children: [
                                                          Image.asset("icons/empty_homework_icon.png",fit: BoxFit.cover,),
                                                          const SizedBox(height: 30),
                                                          const Text("Homework List Not Found",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                                                          const SizedBox(height: 10),
                                                          const Text("Looks like there are no homework record for the",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black38),),
                                                          const Text("day",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black38),)
                                                        ],
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                );
                                              }else{
                                                return Container();
                                              }
                                            }).toList(),
                                          ),
                                        );
                                      },
                                    ),
```

#Everything works fine accept for the problem that i showed in image when i add data of two different date this occurs need your guidence on how can i solve the problem thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are using toList() method. So what happens is for an element dateController.text == homework.savedHomeworkSubmissionDate condition is true and for another is false. With toList() method, you are combining the widgets. You have to check if there is a data within the dates before toList() method. If there is, don't add "Homework List Not Found" widget to list. And if not, show directly "Homework List Not Found" widget without list.

Comment: meaning i have to check for data outside of map?

Comment: Yes, or you can make a list inside of map when condition is true. After map method, show directly that list.

Comment: but without map how can i access that submissionDate like i am little bit confused here